# What is the recursive formula for prime numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, recursion

Like recursive formula for this number series is $L=\{1,5,9,13,17,...\}$
let $T(1)=1$; then formula for all series is $T(N)=T(N-1)+4$; then what will be the generic formula for prime numbers?

Comment: Sadly, nobody knows a good answer for this.

Comment: More sadly , there is a proof that says that a prime generating function does not exist ( a function giving only primes as output). You might want to look it up on the Internet.

Comment: Let $T_1=2$ and after that let $T(N)$ be the smallest number $>1$ coprime to $T(N-1)!$.

Comment: Moreover, primes are " randomly "  distributed . So they do not follow any "simple " generic formula.

Comment: @Avi, that is not true. There is a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb N$ the value $f(n)$ is exactly the $n$th prime.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Avi probably meant this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_of_Prime_Numbers_is_Primitive_Recursive

Answer (score 4):

Let $p_1 = 2$ and let $p_n$ be the smallest number greater than 1 which is not divisible by any of $p_1, \ldots, p_{n-1}$.

Comment: This appears to be the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) translated into the language of sequences.

Comment: This is my definition of what prime numbers are

Answer (score 1):

$p(N) = \min(k>p(N-1), \forall n<N, k \mod p(n)=0)$

is the form given by the definition of prime numbers, unfortunately it doesn't provide a fast way to compute the $n$-th prime number.

Answer (score 1):

I want to show what I found today: https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3940

You can not believe in everything you found in arxiv.org. Still this is an interesting result and what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read this paper. It gives something which is recursive but not useful. I found it very nice though!!https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.05267.pdf

Comment: the link is missing !

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_1=2$. Then define recursively for $k\ge 2$:

$$p_k = \min_{x>1, \gcd(x,P_{k-1})=1} x$$

and 
$$P_k = p_1 \cdots p_k$$.

This is the Sieve of Eratosthenes.